how to integrate the neo4j dashboard to a django webapp?
I am working on a Django webapp that that requires to show the neo4j dashboard to the user, the user should be able to see the nodes and relationships between them like the way it is shown in the neo4j dashboard. I want it to be interactive so that the user can explore the relationships btw each of the nodes, just like they can in the neo-dash app.
Is there any way i can achieve this?
I thought about bringing the neo4j dashboard as an iframe in the webapp but after searching for a solution for a while , i can't find a good way to do it yet.
I currently just query the database for the data and produce graphs with either plotly or chart.js but what i really want to show are the relationships btw the nodes as it is shown in the neo-dash.
